# How can I test for multiple requests using Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, testing

Is there a way to test for multiple requests using Node JS backend?
For example, I want to test multiple scenarios, like:

1. Multiple requests at the same time.
2. Requests on different times, for example, one every hour.
3. Requests that fail and how the server responds at it.

I'm currently using NodeJS with Express.

Comment: are you using any test framework (jest, mocha, chai, etc...) ? if so why not write your self ?

Comment: I'm not using any test framework right now, can I use any of the ones you mention to test my scenarios? o.O

Comment: yes, those are unit test frameworks. I am using `jest` as test framework with `supertest` for making requests to my expressjs app.  You can do same with other framework as well. Just see some tutorial, you'll get all answers for your question.